# AS3 Class Extending Sprite

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I am new to ActionScript so excuse me if this is a stupid question.

So, I created a class, extended the sprite class, and now in the constructor I am trying to set the Sprite's width and height properties which are inherited from the DisplayObject. However, after I set this.width and this.height, and print the values, I get 0 for both.

What the heck is going on?  When I view the livedocs I see that DisplayObject has width and height listed as public properties.  I have been able to instantiate a Sprite directly, and set the width and height after it's been instantiated, so I don't get it.

```
package  {
    import flash.display.*;

    public class ScrollBar extends Sprite {
        public function ScrollBar(width:Number, height:Number) {
            trace(width + "x" + height);
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
            trace(this.width + "x" + this.height);          
    }
}
```

Output:

```
20x400
0x0
```

Comment: I'm not sure about `width:uint, height:uint`. What will happen when you change these to `:Number`, because `this.width` is of type Number.

Comment: Same result even with Number.  You are right though, the attributes should be Number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#width):

> The width is calculated based on the
>   bounds of the content of the display
>   object. When you set the width
>   property, the scaleX property is
>   adjusted accordingly ... Except for
>   TextField and Video objects, a display
>   object with no content (such as an
>   empty sprite) has a width of 0, even
>   if you try to set width to a different
>   value.

You'll need to render something as part of the sprite to get a valid w/h.